# VBA Excel gives overlow by converting to Long

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am new to VBA and to use VBA on excel and write a macro to export an xml file per row (see the example in the print screen). All field represents the right format except the "SSCC" field. This returns an overflow error

I use the following code for reading the excel sheet and creating a xml file:

```
Sub CustomerOutToXML()

 sTemplateXML = _
        "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + _
        "<ENVELOPE>" + vbNewLine + _
            "<TRANSACTION>" + vbNewLine + _
                "<TYPE>" + vbNewLine + "</TYPE>" + vbNewLine + _
            "</TRANSACTION>" + vbNewLine + _
            "<CONTENT>" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + _
                "<DATE>" + vbNewLine + "</DATE>" + vbNewLine + _
                "<SSCC>" + vbNewLine + "</SSCC>" + vbNewLine + _
                "<ORDER>" + vbNewLine + "</ORDER>" + vbNewLine + _
            "</CONTENT>" + vbNewLine + _
        "</ENVELOPE>"

 Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 doc.async = False
 doc.validateOnParse = False
 doc.resolveExternals = False

 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(9)
  lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For lRow = 2 To 10
   sFile = "T:\xxx\xxx\CustomerOutXML\CustomerOut" & .Cells(lRow, 1).Value & ".xml"
   Dim sDATE As String
   Dim sSSCC As Long
   Dim sORDER As String

   sDATE = CStr(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value)
   sSSCC = CLng(.Cells(lRow, 3).Value)
   sORDER = CStr(.Cells(lRow, 4).Value)
   sTransactionType = ActiveSheet.Name

   doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
   doc.getElementsByTagName("DATE")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDATE)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("TYPE")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sTransactionType)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("SSCC")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sSSCC)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("ORDER")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sORDER)


   doc.Save sFile
  Next

 End With

End Sub
```

**Example of the EXcel file**[image: example of the excel format]
Can you please help me to solve this problem

Comment: The max value a long can hold is `2,147,483,647` use a string instead.

Comment: when I convert it to String then I get this value back <SSCC>1,0001640001E+19</SSCC> and not 10001640001000000000

Comment: @Jacob H: You have linked the wrong Visual Basic Long data type there. In Microsoft Office VBA, Long is 4 bytes only -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary.

Comment: @AxelRichter whoops, my bad. Same reason though. Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare sSSCC as `String`. Then instead of using `.Value` with your line: `sSSCC = .Cells(lRow, 3).Value`, use `.Text` instead (and remove the `CLng` as well)

```
Sub CustomerOutToXML()

 sTemplateXML = _
        "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + vbNewLine + _
        "<ENVELOPE>" + vbNewLine + _
            "<TRANSACTION>" + vbNewLine + _
                "<TYPE>" + vbNewLine + "</TYPE>" + vbNewLine + _
            "</TRANSACTION>" + vbNewLine + _
            "<CONTENT>" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + _
                "<DATE>" + vbNewLine + "</DATE>" + vbNewLine + _
                "<SSCC>" + vbNewLine + "</SSCC>" + vbNewLine + _
                "<ORDER>" + vbNewLine + "</ORDER>" + vbNewLine + _
            "</CONTENT>" + vbNewLine + _
        "</ENVELOPE>"

 Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
 doc.async = False
 doc.validateOnParse = False
 doc.resolveExternals = False

 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(9)
  lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

  For lRow = 2 To 10
   sFile = "T:\xxx\xxx\CustomerOutXML\CustomerOut" & .Cells(lRow, 1).Value & ".xml"
   Dim sDATE As String
   Dim sSSCC As String  'Not Long
   Dim sORDER As String

   sDATE = CStr(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value)
   sSSCC = .Cells(lRow, 3).text ' <<< Not .Value
   sORDER = CStr(.Cells(lRow, 4).Value)
   sTransactionType = ActiveSheet.Name

   doc.LoadXML sTemplateXML
   doc.getElementsByTagName("DATE")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sDATE)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("TYPE")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sTransactionType)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("SSCC")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sSSCC)
   doc.getElementsByTagName("ORDER")(0).appendChild doc.createTextNode(sORDER)


   doc.Save sFile
  Next

 End With

End Sub
```